# How to resolve Collections sort in my code?

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I receive the below error which complains about the `Collections.sort();` line:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>       The method sort(List) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments ()

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author apuga
 */
public class Modules implements Comparator<Modules> {

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }

    private String name;
    private String marks;

    Queue allModules = new LinkedList<>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Modules(String name, String marks) {

        this.name = name;
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    public Modules() {

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + "\t" + marks + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + "\t";
    }


    public void addModule() {



        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Modules newM = new Modules(name, marks);

            if (allModules.size() < 4) {
                System.out.println("Enter a module name");
                newM.name = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("name = " + newM.name);
                System.out.println("Enter marks");
                newM.marks = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("marks = " + newM.marks);
                allModules.add(newM);


            } else {
                System.out.println("Adding a module will delete the first module name and marks");
                System.out.println("Enter a module name");
                newM.name = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("name = " + newM.name);
                System.out.println("Enter marks");
                newM.marks = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("marks = " + newM.marks);
                allModules.add(newM);
                allModules.remove();

            }
        }

        System.out.println("Unsorted : "+allModules);
        Collections.sort();// <---- here is where i need help .



    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Modules newmodule = new Modules();
        newmodule.addModule();
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Modules o1, Modules o2) {
        return o1.getMarks().compareTo(o2.getMarks());
    }
}
```

Comment: `Collections.sort();` can’t read your mind. As the compiler message says, it expects a list argument, to know, what it is supposed to sort.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `List` instead of a `Queue` (because it's `Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`). And don't use raw-types!

```
List<Modules> allModules = new LinkedList<>();
```

Then change

```
allModules.remove();
```

to

```
allModules.remove(0);
```

Finally, call `Collections.sort` and display the result like

```
System.out.println("Unsorted : " + allModules);
Collections.sort(allModules, Comparator.comparing(Modules::getMarks));
System.out.println("Sorted : " + allModules);
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfect and i understand it . How about if the  project requirement is to use queue interface.

Comment: Then you would not be able to use [`Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) (which is what I thought you were asking).

Comment: @Gary Are you sure you need to sort the Queue after adding all of the Modules? Or are you implementing a priority queue that should sort them as you insert them?

Comment: When you change the declaration to `LinkedList<Modules> allModules = new LinkedList<>();`, you can still use the queue methods. However, the first thing to change, would be to separate the class managing that queue of modules from the class representing a single module.

Answer (score 0):

> The method sort(List) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments ()

The error tells you that you need to pass a `List` argument to `Collections.sort()`, but you are not passing any arguments.